# Why my OpenFileDialog didn´t work?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rtf

I try to open a textdocument and then I get the message: invalid file format from the `try-catch`. I use Visual Studio 2015 with Visual C# and Windows Forms Application.

Here my code for the open function:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try { 
    // Create an OpenFileDialog to request a file to open.
    OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to look for RTF files.

    openFile1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt| RTF Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf| All (*.*)|*.*";

    // Determine whether the user selected a file from the OpenFileDialog.
    if (openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
       openFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        // Load the contents of the file into the RichTextBox.
        TextBox.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
    }
}//end open
```

I hope you can help me with friendly wishes sniffi.

Comment: What is the full file path and name that you are loading?

Comment: C:\Users\H179850\Documents\Verschiedene Aufzeichnungen (<- that means different records)

Comment: Is it a .txt or .rtf? Because if not, then you will not be able to load it

Comment: At the moment it´s a .txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you don't load a RTF document - see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

> With this version of the LoadFile method, **if** the file being loaded is
>   **not an RTF document**, an **exception will occur**. To load a different type
>   of file such as an ASCII text file, **use** the **other versions of this**
>   **method** that **accept** a value from the **RichTextBoxStreamType** enumeration
>   as a parameter.

So try to use the overloaded [version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d76176b1(v=vs.110).aspx) of this method which accepts the stream type like so (adjust to your needs)

```
TextBox.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Comment: I get the same error message give me a minute i must read the msdn help from RichTextBox.LoadFile Method (String, RichTextBoxStreamType)

Comment: Sry but i didn´t think that i need that, because i want open more than one kind of streams. I must open for example .txt and .dau data.

Comment: Well you have to know upfront what type of stream you are going to open and then use the appropriate stream type. If you don't know if some extension (let's call it .dummy) is plain text or RTF etc., how should the system know how to process it?

Comment: ok at the moment i have a .txt stream but with .PlainText it didn´t work know you why?

Comment: I just wrote a quick sample with RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText and a dummy .txt created with notepad -> it worked. Please try it again with a file created with notepad.

Comment: Ok you right that works, than is the error not on the openDialog, than is it the save dialog that i save it wrong. Thanks for Help